# Rails Devise sessions inadvertently destroyed in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

After successfully logging in to my rails application in production mode, I will attempt to click on one of the filter buttons at the top of the table: 'All Servers', 'In Progress', or 'Remediation.' After pressing one of these buttons, the session will be destroyed and redirect the user back to the login page; however, this **does not occur in the development** environment. In the dev environment, when the user presses one of the filter buttons, the proper scope is applied and no redirection occurs.

After comparing the production logs to the development logs, the error appears to manifest in `Devise::SessionsController#new`

Source code can be found at: https://github.com/herman5/warthog

I have the application hosted on Heroku, so the effects can be seen.

**URL**: http://testdomain.dcmdashboard.com

**email**: moderator@example.com

**password**: password

After logging in and pressing a filter button (`GET "/?order=id_desc&page=1&scope=in_progress"`) in the dev environment:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:15 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UmLj+rzYzRWPr/Y7G5q2Y+/6KptI6X1EzoE7xJCjCIQ=", "user"=>{"email"=>"moderator@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  Tenant Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "tenants".* FROM "tenants" WHERE "tenants"."subdomain" = 'testdomain' LIMIT 1
  User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'moderator@example.com' LIMIT 1
   (1.6ms)  BEGIN
   (2.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = '2013-12-30 00:14:55.058879', "current_sign_in_at" = '2013-12-30 01:40:15.445913', "sign_in_count" = 3, "updated_at" = '2013-12-30 01:40:15.450781' WHERE "users"."id" = 3
   (1.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://testdomain.warthog.dev/admin
Completed 302 Found in 131ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:15 -0600
Processing by Admin::ServersController#index as HTML
  Tenant Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "tenants".* FROM "tenants" WHERE "tenants"."subdomain" = 'testdomain' LIMIT 1
  User Load (32.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
   (2.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "servers" WHERE ('t')
   (2.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "servers" WHERE (build_stage = '2 - In Progress' OR build_stage = '4 - Build Team QA')
   (4.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "servers" WHERE (build_stage = '7 - Build Team Remediation' OR build_stage = '13 - SecOps Remediation')
   (2.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT 1 AS count_column FROM "servers" LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT 1 AS count_column FROM "servers" LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
   (2.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "servers"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT 1 AS count_column FROM "servers" LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
  Server Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "servers".* FROM "servers" ORDER BY "servers"."id" desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
  Rendered /Users/Dylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-ec9996406df5/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (354.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 403ms (Views: 342.4ms | ActiveRecord: 54.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:15 -0600


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:15 -0600
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/lib/namespace.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:15 -0600
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/components/jquery.aa.checkbox-toggler.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:15 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/components/jquery.aa.checkbox-toggler.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
Served asset /active_admin/lib/namespace.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)



Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:15 -0600

Started GET "/assets/active_admin/components/jquery.aa.dropdown-menu.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:15 -0600
Served asset /jquery-ui.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/components/jquery.aa.table-checkbox-toggler.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:16 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/components/jquery.aa.dropdown-menu.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/components/jquery.aa.popover.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:16 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/components/jquery.aa.table-checkbox-toggler.js - 304 Not Modified (4ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/pages/batch_actions.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:16 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/components/jquery.aa.popover.js - 304 Not Modified (5ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/pages/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:16 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/pages/batch_actions.js - 304 Not Modified (4ms)
Served asset /active_admin/pages/application.js - 304 Not Modified (3ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:16 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/application.js - 304 Not Modified (9ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/base.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:16 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/base.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:16 -0600
Served asset /active_admin.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/?order=id_desc&page=1&scope=in_progress" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:26 -0600
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
Processing by Admin::ServersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"order"=>"id_desc", "page"=>"1", "scope"=>"in_progress"}
  Tenant Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "tenants".* FROM "tenants" WHERE "tenants"."subdomain" = 'testdomain' LIMIT 1
   (2.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "servers" WHERE ('t')
   (4.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "servers" WHERE (build_stage = '2 - In Progress' OR build_stage = '4 - Build Team QA')
   (2.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "servers" WHERE (build_stage = '7 - Build Team Remediation' OR build_stage = '13 - SecOps Remediation')
   (2.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT 1 AS count_column FROM "servers" WHERE (build_stage = '2 - In Progress' OR build_stage = '4 - Build Team QA') LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT 1 AS count_column FROM "servers" WHERE (build_stage = '2 - In Progress' OR build_stage = '4 - Build Team QA') LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "servers" WHERE (build_stage = '2 - In Progress' OR build_stage = '4 - Build Team QA')
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT 1 AS count_column FROM "servers" WHERE (build_stage = '2 - In Progress' OR build_stage = '4 - Build Team QA') LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
  Server Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "servers".* FROM "servers" WHERE (build_stage = '2 - In Progress' OR build_stage = '4 - Build Team QA') ORDER BY "servers"."id" desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
  Rendered /Users/Dylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-ec9996406df5/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (359.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 373ms (Views: 349.4ms | ActiveRecord: 19.5ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:26 -0600


Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:26 -0600
Served asset /jquery-ui.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:26 -0600
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/components/jquery.aa.checkbox-toggler.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:26 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/components/jquery.aa.checkbox-toggler.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/components/jquery.aa.popover.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:26 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/components/jquery.aa.popover.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/pages/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:26 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/pages/application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:26 -0600


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/lib/namespace.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:26 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
Served asset /active_admin/lib/namespace.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/components/jquery.aa.dropdown-menu.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:26 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/components/jquery.aa.dropdown-menu.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/components/jquery.aa.table-checkbox-toggler.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:26 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/components/jquery.aa.table-checkbox-toggler.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/pages/batch_actions.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:26 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/pages/batch_actions.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/base.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:26 -0600
Served asset /active_admin/base.js - 304 Not Modified (12ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:40:26 -0600
Served asset /active_admin.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
```

After logging in and pressing the filter button (`GET "/?order=id_desc&page=1&scope=in_progress"`) in the production environment:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:47:10 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UmLj+rzYzRWPr/Y7G5q2Y+/6KptI6X1EzoE7xJCjCIQ=", "user"=>{"email"=>"moderator@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Redirected to http://testdomain.warthog.dev/admin
Completed 302 Found in 116ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:47:11 -0600
Processing by Admin::ServersController#index as HTML
  Rendered /Users/Dylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-ec9996406df5/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (115.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 126ms (Views: 97.7ms | ActiveRecord: 24.6ms)
Started GET "/?order=id_desc&page=1&scope=in_progress" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-29 19:47:23 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"order"=>"id_desc", "page"=>"1", "scope"=>"in_progress"}
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.haml (0.3ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 7.2ms | ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
```

Comment: Load balancer is sending you to different servers across a session?

Comment: @Denis I don't think that's the case, as the same behavior is encountered on my local machine

Comment: Notice how Devise::SessionsController#create isnt accessing the database (it doesn't count as a login). Have you run the migrations on production? Why is it still redirecting?

Comment: It seams to be a problem with ActiveAdmin. Can you show us how you have configured it?

Comment: @rlecaro2 All migrations hav been run on production (heroku). Notice how I can still login to the application, but it's only after pressing a 'filter' or 'cancel' button that my session is destroyed

Comment: You're right. Could it be that the precompilation of assets interferes somehow with active_admin? Maybe you should share its config and/or some controller methods involved.

Is it possible that your permission system logs you out (so if you're trying to access a restricted scope the session is destroyed)?

Comment: Interesting. I copied over all settings from `development.rb` into `production.rb` and the same effects still appeared.

Comment: I've updated the question with a link to the source code

Comment: Try: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#heroku

Comment: @rlecaro2 unfortunately that didn't fix it

Comment: The hosted example is working fine for me here - I'm filtering without any loss of session. Was the problem resolved?

Comment: @ChrisHeald Try pressing 'All Servers' or 'In Progress'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with the hosted version I think the problem is in the links used to sort the server table. You currently use the link http://testdomain.dcmdashboard.com/?order=operating_system_desc to order the table by the operating system. If you use http://testdomain.dcmdashboard.com/admin/?order=operating_system_desc instead (with /admin/ in front of your query param) your session don't get killed and you don't have to log in again.

This problem does only exist for those columns with your self defined collections in `app/admin/servers.rb`.  It may be a bug in the current development version of active_admin or a missing parameter.

Please add a value for the default namespace in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`:

```
config.default_namespace = :admin
```

Should the problem persist try to use a stable version of active_admin like version 0.6.2 and try it again.

Comment: Very interesting! Unfortunately updating the gem and ActiveAdmin initializer did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Although this did not solve the problem, I am accepting your answer because I believe this must be resolved within the ActiveAdmin source code

Comment: That's not how answers on Stack Overflow work... This didn't fix your problem, so you shouldn't mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Only difference between production and development is that production logs you out when you follow links that get you out of the /admin namespace, problem is present in both cases, it looks like an ActiveAdmin bug.

Keeping in touch with good people at active admin will help https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2839

Also, while using ActiveAdmin for VERY simple apps and scaffolding is well and OK, you will rue the day you decided doing anything complex with it, in the time lost fixing this one scope you probably could have built the entire thing from scratch using ransack and devise